# How to handle order line level dimension when used along side a Order level measure?

Tags: powerbi, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I have a header-detail type of requirement.

For example:

My dimensions are product, customer, DateTable

My fact table is `FactOrders (columns: order num, prod_id, cust_id, date, num of items, total amount, cost of pkg)`.

This is a star schema.

There was a new requirement to add/show data for order line items, and to make a drill through such that when a user clicks on an order they should be able to drill through to a new page showing the order lines.

So I merged the `FactOrders` with `FactOrderLines`.

Since cost of pkg is an order level figure (and repeats for each line due to the merge), following measure is created:

`Cost of pkg = SUMX(VALUES('FactOrders'[Order Num]), CALCULATE(MIN('FactOrders'[Cost of pkg])))`

In a table visual if I place the `OrderNum` and above measure I get correct result.

But if I add the Product Name (from Product dimension, which is only applicable to Order Lines) into the visual, I get an incorrect result. How to handle this?

Comment: Expand more on "I get an incorrect result" - how is it incorrect? And just to be clear, you now only have one fact table as you have merged them. What are the columns of the new merged fact table? I assume Product is in OrderLines and not in Orders. If you could update your question with both fact table columns and the new merged one, that would help. Lastly, if possible to share a sample/mock PBIX then that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

All your measures need to be at the same grain in a fact table. Where you have a grain of order items but measures at the order level you have a number of options (this is not a necessarily a definitive list of options):

- Allocate the order measure to the line items

  - Accurately if there are business rules that can be defined to do this
  - Arbitrarily if necessary (equally to all lines, all to one line, etc)
- Create a dummy line item to hold the order measure e.g. with a product code of “pkg”

Which option you choose depends on how you are going to use the data and how easy it is to include/exclude, as necessary, the order measures from your processes